# Wordpress.org - Content not displaying once published

Tags: wordpress

This is the first time Ive come across this issue.

I have some content (charts based on php/mysql) that shows in preview mode only but once the post/page is published, it doesn't show a all.

For those charts to work, Im also uploading this into the `<head>` section

```
<script src="charts4php/lib/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="charts4php/lib/js/chartphp.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="charts4php/lib/js/chartphp.css">
```

Here is the page that doesn't show the charts for some reason:
[Click here](http://sa-sim.com/chart-test-2/)

Now for the charts to show, the only way is to create a new post/page and copy/paste in all the code and hit 'Preview'. Then again, once I hit 'Publish' it just vanishes and need to recreate a new page/post again...

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Try using the inspector in chrome to see whether resources fail to load

Comment: Thanks @DavidBrossard, but how to read the inspector properly? any specific tab/location so I can copy paste what I read.

Comment: Right click on any element and do inspect. Then go to the network tab and refresh your page

Comment: Thanks, indeed all files related to the charts show 404 error (not found)...although they are well included in the Head section along with other files...any tip David?

Comment: If they show 404 then the inclusion code is there but the path is wrong.

Comment: David, you're the man! the root domain name was missing in the path... it strangely worked in Preview mode but not in production. Please add an answer so I can select it to give you credit! thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand why an article is working in the preview mode and not in the published, it is useful to resort to Google Chrome's Inspector. It provides 2 neat tools:

- a console which shows any potential Javascript errors
- a network manager which shows which resources are requested, which are found (200) and which are missing (404)

If the preview works and the published article does not there are at least 2 possible reasons:

- the template framework you use includes Javascript or CSS that conflicts with what you are trying to show - the charts
- the path to the charts' dependencies is wrong.

Very often in Wordpress, using relative paths is not a great idea since the preview and the published version may be on different paths. Try that and see.

Comment: Exactly, I had to use absolute paths to make it work on the published version. Relative paths were good enough only for previewing. Thanks again!